# Populating the value of a Label

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I am using the MVC architecture (i have gone through the docs on MVC, but i am still lost here) and i need to know how to populate the records on to my Label. I know that i have to get this done by Stores.

I have loaded the values from the store, but unable to display it on my Panel for some reason. here's my code;

Most of the examples/books demonstrates how to display in a grid, but not a label (I know it has to be the same logic, but i am lost). And it shows how to write to a DB/JSON file and not display the values.

I need to display the COUNTRYNAME in the Label text. This is an example code that i am doing to understand this, can some one help me ?

```
Ext.define ('ProjectDisplayExample.model.Country',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    //
    fields:['countryid','countryname']
    //
});
```

STORE

```
Ext.define('ProjectDisplayExample.store.Country',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'ProjectDisplayExample.model.Country',
    remoteGroup:true,
    proxy: {
        actionMethods : {
            read   : 'POST',
        },
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/server/country.php'
    }   
});
```

VIEW

```
Ext.define('ProjectDisplayExample.view.CountryWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.countrywindow',
    ...........

    initComponent: function() {
        var st = Ext.getStore('Country');
        st.load();
        this.items = [
        {
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'north',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    // NEED TO DISPLAY COUNTRT NAME FROM THE STORE HERE
                }]
            }]
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
var store = ... // Your store
store.on('load', function() {
    // here store is loaded and you can do anything you want with it
    console.log('store is loaded. number of records = ', store.getCount());
}, this, { single: true });

store.load; // I ADDED THIS LINE.................... <---------
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
this.items = [
            {
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'north',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'label',
                        name : f
                    }]
                }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will not post a code sample to exactly solve your question, but I will give you couple points:

- Store contains array or records. So you can't just say `give me country name` from the store. You need first to get a record, for example:  `var r = store.getAt(0)`, and only after that you can get countyname field `var f = r.get('countryname')`.
- `Load()` method is asynchronous, so you can just execute it somewhere in the code and assume that for the very next line your store is ready. You need to subscribe to the `load` event, something like:

  > ```
  > var store = ... // Your store
  > store.on('load', function() {
  >     // here store is loaded and you can do anything you want with it
  >     console.log('store is loaded. number of records = ', store.getCount());
  > }, this, { single: true });
  > store.load();
  > ```
- Labels as in `xtype: label` are actually very rarely used in ExtJs. What exactly are you trying to display in that panel? But anyhow... after you get data out of the store you can use something like `update()` or `setValue()` or any other method to update component.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. But, Unless i add `store.load()` the load event (`store.on('load', function()`) doesn't get executed. I have updated my post above, adding the code `store.load();`. Could you check if i am doing the right thing ?

Comment: Yes, you're right - you first subscribe to `load` event, and then you execute load(). I missed that. I will update my answer.

Comment: Everything works fine, I am able to display the text on a `Console.log` successfully. But, the panel loads before the store.load(), hapence. therefore, the Text value is not printed on the panel. I don't think i have to paste the Panel code inside the `load` event. Is there a way i could refresh the panel, so it would load the Text value ?

Comment: You need to find that control using query() function. Check out http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query this article

Comment: According to my code its `        var panelsArray = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#label panel');
`. And then how should i add the text. I am seriously lost here :S

Comment: after you found array of panels do something like  `panelsArray[0].down('label').setValue('My Value')`

Comment: It says `panelsArray[0].up("label") is undefined`. Is it because i got `var panelsArray = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#label panel'); ` wrong ?

Comment: down('label'). I though you had label inside the panel.

Comment: Well, I don't know your element hierarchy. You will have to try and debug different things.

Comment: I am still having the same error. I have updated my element hierarchy. Could you help me here ?